# How to create a set of values from multiple list in Python

Tags: python, json, list

I have below data in `config.json`:

```
{
  "data1": [7, 8],
  "data2": [2015, 2016],
  "data3": [5, 10],
}
```

It has 3 list with length as 2 but it can have multiple list with n length. I have to read this data and then create a list of list which should have all the values just like set. So output should look like below:

```
[
    [7, 2015, 5],
    [7, 2015, 10],
    [7, 2016, 5],
    [7, 2016, 10],
    [8, 2015, 5],
    [8, 2015, 10],
    [8, 2016, 5],
    [8, 2016, 10]
]


json_data = open("config.json")
config = json.load(json_data)
json_data.close()

data_list = []
for be in config["data1"]:
    for eof in config["data2"]:
        for bd in config["data3"]:
            data_list.append(bd)
```

But I am unable to understand how do I modify the data to have output like above. Can anyone please give some suggestion. Please help. Thanks

Comment: I am a little confused,  will the number of lists be dynamic and you want to find every combination of those? Is the length ([7,8]) of 2 items static, or is it also dynamic?

Comment: @ZaidAlShattle length of list is dynamic but I can say number of list can be static

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some information about a_guest's answer, as you seems to have some trouble understand it.

```
json_data = open("config.json")
config = json.load(json_data)
json_data.close()

cproduct = list(itertools.product(*config.values()))
```

`product` function will give you the cartesian product, that's exactly what you need : all possible combination of elements from different set. We basically use it as `product(set_1, set_2, ..., set_n)`.

Here, `set_1` should be the list stored with the `"data1"` key, `set_2` with `"data2"` and so on. So you could basically write `it.product(config['data1'], config['data2'], config['data3'])`.

But how can we deals with new keys in the json without changing our code ?

To achieve this, guest_a relies on two things :

- `config.values()` which return a list of every values, so in your case a list containing all the list defined in your json. This way, you'll get the new list if you add a new `"data4"` key into your json file.
- Unpacking `*` operator, which allow us to use any iterable as a list of arguments.

So basically, `it.product(*config.values())` is equivalent to `it.product(config["data1"], ..., config["data_n"])`, but is much more flexible.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```py
list(it.product(*data.values()))
```

Comment: Do you mean I have to run this in a for loop where `data` will be the data from config file

Comment: I assumed `data` is the example dictionary you provided in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Use `itertools.product` which gives the Cartesian product of a series of iterables:

```
from itertools import product
data = {'data1': [7, 8], 'data2': [2015, 2016], 'data3': [5, 10]}
cprod = product(*data.values())
for cp in cprod:
    print(cprod)
(7, 2015, 5)
(7, 2015, 10)
(7, 2016, 5)
(7, 2016, 10)
(8, 2015, 5)
(8, 2015, 10)
(8, 2016, 5)
(8, 2016, 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

you have done all the work
just add

```
    data_list = []
    for be in config["data1"]:
        for eof in config["data2"]:
            for bd in config["data3"]:
                data_list.append([be,eof,bd])
```